# How to embed iframe into the entire window (not be confused with fullscreen) with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am embedding a link into an iframe:

```
<div class="container hidden" id="timeline" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe allowfullscreen="true" class="embed-responsive-item container well well-small span6" frameborder="0" id="timeline_view" mozallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" src="" webkitallowfullscreen="true">
            </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not occupying the entire window. But it occupies a small rectangle. I played around with other options:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/

```
<!-- 1:1 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    <!-- Timeline Viewer -->
    <div class="container hidden" id="timeline">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" id="timeline_view" mozallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" src="" webkitallowfullscreen="true">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```